# Why do we set offset (0.5) in single shot detector?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, papers

In the paper [SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325), under section 2.2 - (4), why do we add an offset of **0.5** to x, y in generating the anchor boxes across feature maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer coordinates refer to the top-left corner of a pixel. Adding 0.5 to both x and y gives you the center location of a pixel instead.